# Autofill Value in a cell based on other cell

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Is there any way to get a specific value "66" in "B1" when I Put Text "Ok" in "A1" without entering Formula in "B1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Worksheet_Change` event. Try below codes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Val(Target.Value) = 66 Then
            Range("A1") = "Ok"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your Great help Bro it works for me I make little changes and get the result. Jazak ALLAH

Comment: `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Val(Target.Value) = ok Then
            Range("B1") = "66"`

Comment: Sir how can I get the same results by giving Range("A1:A30")

Comment: Change target range from A1 to A1:A30.

Comment: And if it helps then tick mark the answer.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73512110/19857235]

Comment: Yes, you have to use offset method.